# How to animate LayoutParams x and y in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm new to android.
I have the following code:

```
// layoutParams of type WindowManager.LayoutParams
layoutParams.x = someX;
layoutParams.y = someY;
windowManager.updateViewLayout(someView, layoutParams);
```

How do I animate this change? Something like translation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ValueAnimator`:

```
int beginValue = 0;
int endValue = 100;

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(beginValue, endValue);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.x = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        layoutParams.y = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, params);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather use Property Value Holders when animating across x an y.

```
public void animate(final View v, int startX, int endX, int startY, int endY) {

    PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("x", startX, endX);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("y", startY, endY);

    ValueAnimator translator = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(pvhX, pvhY);

    translator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.x = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x");
            layoutParams.y = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y");
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, layoutParams);
        }
    });

    translator.setDuration(100);
    translator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I've found to similar problem is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g

In my case I have a `RelativeLayout` and want to change its `android:layout_below` value programmatically (it's parent is also `RelativeLayout`).

So in `onCreate` I've put:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = rlListLayout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

and then for example in `onClick` method changed layout params:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rl.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.dummy);
rl.setLayoutParams(params);
```

That's it. 5 lines of code and no need to calculate position nor measure anything.